# GS1 Codebar on ZPL Batch Lot

Tags: c#, zpl

I have the following problem, where I work I am trying to optimize the printing of ID tags. However some products have numbers and letters in their batch, when the product has only numbers the GS1 barcode label works well, but when it has letters and / or symbols together it removes some of the barcode.

Here's an example:

Item: 410234
Lot: FLS00013 / 19

How GS1 Code Exits Using Zebra Designer:

```
^FD>;>80200000004102341719122910>6FLS>50001>63/19^FS
```

Recalling that I don't use Zebra Designer to print the labels, I use my application for this, but I don't find anywhere guidance on these escape symbols inside the ZPL code.

My application basically reads a text file with the ready label template and replaces a few fields:

```
^FD>;>802[ITEM]17[BEST]10[LOT]^FS
```

Comment: Which barcode command do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) you can find a description of the control characters (starting with `>`) inside the section of the barcode command `^BC` (Code 128).

> [image: Code 128 Invocation characters]